# Running a Powershell Script from PHP

Tags: php, powershell

The following I can run in the command Prompt with no problem:

```
powershell -noexit "& ""C:\wamp\www\mypowersher.ps1”""
```

But I want to add it to my PHP script.  Is it possible?
I tried using `exec` but it did not work.

```
    $psPath ='"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"';
    $psDIR = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\mypowersher.ps1';  
    $psScript = 'mypowersher.ps1';
    $runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
    $runCMD = $psPath." "& ".$runScript." 2>&1"";   

exec( $runCMD);
```

Comment: $psPath ='"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"';
$psDIR = 'C:\\wamp\\www\\mypowersher.ps1';  
$psScript = 'mypowersher.ps1';
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." "& ".$runScript." 2>&1"";   

exec( $runCMD);

Comment: @user874339 please edit your question rather than posting  a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possibly a problem with configuration since your description is unclear. So try turning `safe_mode= on` on your WAMP server.

Additionally you can try [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) if it makes any differences.

Comment: Thanks turning safe_mode= on fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Try it this way

$psPath = '"C:\\Windows\\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\\powershell.exe"';
$psDIR = "C:\\wamp\\www\\";
$psScript = "mypower.ps1";
$runScript = $psDIR. $psScript;
$runCMD = $psPath." ".$runScript." 2>&1";

exec( $runCMD,$out,$ret);


$output= shell_exec($runCMD); 
echo( '<pre>' );
echo( $output );
echo( '</pre>' );
```